# Django simple history history_change_reason - how to set instance from class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wired up an object to use simple history and I see the historical table being correctly populated. I would like to also use history_change_reason field for more metadata. The difference from  [instructions](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/historical_model.html) is that on our system we use objects.create_or_update inside a classmethod. It works if I set changeHistory on the class parameter. However, I would like to set it on the instance of the class. What is a good way to do it?

```
class SimpleHistoryTest(models.Model):
   ....
   history = HistoricalRecords()
   ...

   @classmethod
   def update_or_create_override (cls, feature):
       ...

       cls.changeReason = features # this works. However, this is changed on all instances of class

       SimpleHistoryTest.objects.update_or_create(
        prop1='value1',    
       )
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I can't tell which parts are supposed to be inside the method, at class level, or outside the class completely.

Comment: And also explain exactly how you're calling this and how you expect it to work.